# How to perform a 'one-liner' assignment on all elements of a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

Given a list of lists `lol`, I would like to do in one line

```
for ele in lol:
    ele[1] = -2
```

I tried

```
lol = map(lambda x: x[1] = -2, lol)
```

But its not possible to perform an assignment in a lambda function.

Comment: If you just want one line, did you try taking the newline out?: `for ele in lol: ele[1] = -2`

Comment: Why do you want to do this, what is wrong with using your for loop approach?

Comment: @cdarke: One-line compound statements are against PEP 8.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham mainly out of curiosity

Comment: @zondo:  agreed, but the OP asked for a one-liner.  It is also against the spirit of PEP 8 to use a less than obvious way to do it.  Using `setitem()` for such a simple operation is obfuscation and in my opinion a bigger sin than a one-line statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not change your own approach but to answer your question:

```
lol = [[1,3],[3,4]]
from operator import setitem

map(lambda x: setitem(x, 1, -2), lol)
print(lol)
[[1, -2], [3, -2]]
```

It does the assignment in place but you are basically using map for side effects and creating a list of None's:

```
In [1]: lol = [[1, 3], [3, 4]]


In [2]: from operator import setitem

In [3]: map(lambda x: setitem(x, 1, -2), lol)
Out[3]: [None, None]

In [4]: lol
Out[4]: [[1, -2], [3, -2]]
```

So really stick to your own for loop logic.

They simple loop is also the more performant:

```
In [13]: %%timeit                                          
lol = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] for _ in range(100000)]
map(lambda x: setitem(x, 1, -2), lol)
   ....: 

10 loops, best of 3: 45.4 ms per loop

In [14]: 

In [14]: %%timeit                                          
lol = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] for _ in range(100000)]
for sub in lol:
    sub[1] = -2
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 31.7 ms per
```

The only time map. filter etc.. really do well is if you can call them with a builtin function or method i.e `map(str.strip, iterable)`, once you include a lambda the performance will usually take a big hit.

Comment: Would this be quicker than the for loop?

Comment: @rwolst, I find map, filter etc.. is only really efficient  when you can call it without a lambda, once a lambda gets involved you take a big performance hit

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `setitem()` function in `operator`:

```
from operator import setitem

lol = [setitem(x, 1, -2) or x for x in lol]
```

You can also take out the `lol` re-definition and just do this:

```
from operator import setitem

map(lambda x: setitem(x, 1, -2), lol)
```

or

```
from operator import setitem

[setitem(x, 1, -2) for x in lol]
```

I must agree with Padraic, though, your approach looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
>>> lol = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> lol =[[-2] + mas for x, *mas in lol]
>>> lol
[[-2, 2, 3], [-2, 5, 6], [-2, 8, 9]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not the most efficient way, I'm just posting it to get feedbacks about it's Quality and if it's a Pythonic way to do so otherwise I will delete it if it's downvoted, so:

```
>>> lol
[[1, 3], [3, 4]]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> list(map(lambda x:x.__setitem__(1, -2), lol)) #list required in Python 3
[None, None]
>>> lol
[[1, -2], [3, -2]]
```

Comment: It's not. Don't use `map` if you don't actually want the list/iterator that it produces. Use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Definitely not pythonic but neither are any of the other solutions here, I think  essentially it was a question about if it were possible more than is it a good idea so +1, another way to skin the cat

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback, I just hate the generated list/iterator as @chepner mentioned, is it possible to avoid it using the same method?...Or it has to be through a `for` loop

Comment: @PadraicCunningham .. LOL ..:D